# Add timestamp when adding a document to Cloudant / CouchDB

Tags: timestamp, couchdb, cloudant

I want to add a timestamp to every document added to Cloudant / CouchDB. My client is a low power IoT device that doesn't know the current time (NTP operation costs too much power).

From what I have read I can use a design document for this, but the client has to trigger this manually after inserting the document. This will be too power-intensive for the client as it has to do two HTTP requests instead of one.

Is there any way to facilitate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a design document is the best solution in your case.

You need to define an update function (see [this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions)) for full documentation.

In this update function, you will be able to modify the document passed to this function to set a timestamp as it's _id.

You don't need to create the document before calling this update handler. You can simply send a request with the document inside the request body.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about the design documents incorrectly.

My current update function:

`{
  "_id": "_design/update_handlers",
  "updates": {
    "add_with_timestamp": "function (doc, req) { var measurement = JSON.parse(req.body); measurement._id = new Date(); return [measurement, 'created']; }"
  }
}`

I call it by POSTing a regular document to:
https://$host/$database/_design/update_handlers/_update/add_with_timestamp

It also still works on an account that only has write rights.